# Sharing gutter space between line numbers and YCM markers

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, line-numbers

Is there a way, if the 'number' option is enabled to show line numbers, to make YouCompleteMe show errors and warnings by changing the line number colours instead of adding extra width to the gutter to show ">> "?

Comment: I thought about it too and no, I don't think that's possible. Line numbers seems to be hardcoded feature and you have only two options `number` and `relativenumber`

Answer (score 3):

You could try and use [DynamicSigns](https://github.com/chrisbra/DynamicSigns). The documentation includes an example to show relative line numbers every 5 lines. Maybe you can adopt the example and use this plugin combined with YCM.